# Изменение атрибутов формы label в powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

Проблема такова,я новенький в powershell и хотел бы создать простое приложение с gui
Создал само окно и форму label

```
add-type -Assembly system.windows.forms

$main_form=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text='Healthy life'
$main_form.Width=500
$main_form.Height=700
$main_form.AutoSize=$true

$label=New-object System.Windows.forms.label
$label.text="Здравствуйте!"
$label.location=New-object System.Drawing.Point(180,70)
$main_form.controls.add($label)


$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

Но изучаю свойства $label никак не могу как понять,как изменить её размер,через какое свойство это делается?

Comment: Те же самые свойства, что и у формы: Width, Height, а также Size. См. [Label](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Возможно вам нужно изменить размер самого текста? Тогда меняйте шрифт (Font).

Comment: Я говорю не только о шрифте,но и о занимаемом месте самого поля,например поля progressbar.Я пытался изменить значение Height,но этого не происходит,система не меняет значение Height

Comment: Я попробовал - меняет. Убедитесь, что `AutoSize` выставлено в `false`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,я добавил в код `$label.Size=new Size($label.Width(200),$label.Height(100))` но всё равно не работает,пишет **Сбой вызова метода из-за отсутствия в [System.Windows.Forms.Label] метода с именем "Width".**,можете показать как вы написали код для изменения размера формы label?

Comment: Width и Height - это _свойства_, а не _методы_. Пишите так же, как вы сами написали для формы.